# How to use Dart's dev_compiler for simple libs?

Tags: dart, interop

I am experimenting with Dart's [dev_compiler](https://github.com/dart-lang/dev_compiler). I think I am missing a couple of steps how to get it working in a browser. 
Currently all the resources I found regarding it are:
[Usage](https://github.com/dart-lang/dev_compiler/blob/master/USAGE.md)

**What I'd like** to do is:

1. Create a simple single class library package in Dart
2. Compile it to ES6
3. Use that compiled library in Canary from JS

Problems:

- running `dartdevc -o outputdir lib/mylib.dart` prompts me to specify the `--runtime-dir` option. What should that directory be? I use Win dev machine, I specified it to be `Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\dev_compiler-0.1.1+1\lib\runtime`
- After that, compilation succeeds, however in the compiled .js file there are a references to a `dart` variable. I assume this should be the one defined in `dart_runtime.js`. This brings me to the *question*: what exactly do I have to import in an HTML file to get my transcompiled dart lib work? (scripts srcs)

For now I did not get as far as to use the transcompiled library from a browser. Any tips how to do that would be appreciated.

## Update:

I wrote a little post about my experiences with dev_compiler: [dev_compiler experiment](http://goo.gl/32rNBU)

Answer (score 1):

This easiest way to play around with this is to use the "server" mode:

> dartdevc -o outputdir --server foo.dart

That should generate a foo.html in the output directory that shows you what gets linked in.

For now, this will bring in all the Dart libraries - regardless of what your class actually uses.  You may find that you only need a small subset to run your code.